# How to accept unlimited closures in a Python function?

Tags: python, recursion, closures

I have a code like below :

```
    # Define a function
    def foo(x):
        # inner function "bar"
        def bar(y):
            q = 10
            # inner function "baz"
            def baz(z):
                print("Locals: ", locals())
                print("Vars: ", vars())
                return x + y + q + z
            return baz
        return bar

    # Locals: {'y': 20, 'x': 10, 'z': 30, 'q': 10}
    # Vars: {'y': 20, 'x': 10, 'z': 30, 'q': 10}

print(foo(10)(20)(30)) # 70
```

how can i modify the above function to accept unlimited calls and also to accept strings... ?

and do we have to use imilar to how we write a decorators or is there any other way to achieve this ?

```
print(foo(90)) 
print(foo()(90)) 
print(foo()()(90)) 
print(foo()()()('ss'))
```

Comment: What is `foo()()()('ss')` supposed to do?

Comment: print foooooss .. printing o for every empty ()

Comment: ... but it is preferable in some way to `print('foooss')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure captures are just a distraction here, and so is handling `90` and `ss` in different ways,<sup>1</sup> so let's throw all of that out and just solve the problem you're struggling with.

First, you want a function that does one thing if called with an argument, and a different thing if called without an argument. That's easy; just use a parameter with a default value, or use `*args`.

Second, the "different thing" you want to do is to return a function that recursively does the same thing as your function, except for sticking an extra `'o'` in the result. When defining a recursive data structure—whether it's a recursive closure, or a recursive defaultdict, the easiest way to do it is usually to use recursion.

For example:

```
def foo(x=None, *, _chain=0):
    if x is None:
        def bar(*args):
            return foo(*args, _chain=_chain+1)
        return bar
    else:
        return 'f' + 'o'*_chain + x
```

You *could* rewrite `bar` as a decorator, and `return bar(foo)`, but that seems unnecessary. It wouldn't change the fact that the key here is that `foo` returns a function that calls `foo`.

---

<sub>1. If you don't know how to do that, just `if isinstance(x, str):`. Or, if you want to get fancy, look up `functools.singledispatch`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. this is exactly what I was looking for... On what topics should my learning be focused on in order to solve these kinds of problems (Python)?

Comment: @vkk07 Well, a function like this is kind of a weird thing to do in Python. If you really want to get deep into recursion, closures, etc., you might be a lot better off learning Scheme, Haskell, OCaml, F#, or Scala. Then, working out how (and when/whether) to map different things back to Python is a great learning experience. And then maybe work through [CTM](https://www.amazon.com/Concepts-Techniques-Models-Computer-Programing/dp/8120326857/), which is all about that kind of mapping, but one level of abstraction higher.